# IOS Push notifications with AWS SNS

Tags: php, ios, flash, amazon-web-services

I have a flash based ios app that I am currently testing on phone/ipod.

I have added push notification to the app and I am receiving device tokens from apple.

I have added those tokens to AWS SNS APN SandBox

The platform Application ARN looks like

```
arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:7860818154325:app/APNS_SANDBOX/gamename
```

I have added tokens to the PAA and they look like:

```
token: f63d05538cd7d9b86c76188dbfeb42edf26a1e23b47334a02a205e0fb54a812a
endpoint ARN: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:7860818154325:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/gamename/7412740a-79e4-3b71-8e7f-56e127bc4cg1
```

Sending out the notification via PHP:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$sns = Aws\Sns\SnsClient::factory(array(
'key'    => 'mykey',
'secret' => 'mysecret',
'region' => 'us-east-1'
));

$snsmessage = $sns->publish(array(
'TargetArn' => "$endpoint",
'Message' => 'A game is waiting for you to play'
));
```

(where $endpoint = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:7860818154325:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/gamename/7412740a-79e4-3b71-8e7f-56e127bc4cg1")

$snsmessage returns a message ID, so it looks like it is sending the message.

However no message is ever received on the phone.

I have tried manually sending a message from the SNS portal and the same issue. IT sends with no error message but it never arrives.

I am building the app as "device testing" and I am using provisionprofile that has push notifcation enabled.

I am not sure where to start looking to find the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you enabled APNS? http://quickblox.com/developers/How_to_create_APNS_certificates

Comment: Yes, it is enabled and tokens are being received by the phone, but messages sent to the phone appear to be sending but are never received.